# Recursion without using exit statement.,

Tags: c, recursion, return

I write a program to find the prime factor of a number entered.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void pf(int, int,int);
int main()
{
    int num,i=2,j=2;
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    pf(num,i,j);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
void pf(int num,int i, int j)
{
    int rem, rem2; 
    if(num==1)
        exit(1);
    if(i>j)
    {
        rem=i%j;
        if(rem==0)
            pf(num,i+1,2);
        if(rem!=0)
            pf(num,i,j+1);
    }
    if(i==j)
    {
        rem2=num%i;
        if(rem2==0)
        {
            printf("%d, ", i);
            num=num/i;
            pf(num,i,j);
        }
        if(num!=1)
            pf(num,i+1,2);
    }
}
```

I am studying recursion, but I often use `exit()` statements. It become very difficult when I use `return` statement. Can anyone tell me how to replace the exit statement in this program by `return` statement. This program is working well, but while entering a large number, program crashes everytime.

Comment: just replace return 1 in the place of exit(1)

Comment: @Siraj What is the prime factor of a number?

Comment: @Siraj Also what is the meaning of the statement  if(TRUE) ?

Comment: prime factors are the simply factors of a number, like,
24 have prime factors 2,2,2,3,
18 have prime factors 2,3,3,
means, multiplying these numbers will give the number entered.
all the factors of the number should be prime., 2,3,5,7,11 and so on!!

Comment: ohhh, just replace TRUE by rem2==0

Comment: Have any problem after adding returnt 1 instead of exit(1)??

Comment: @Nafeeur Yeah, program crashes if I simple replacement, perhaps due to stack overflow.

Comment: Function is declared as void he has to change definition of function .

Comment: what will be ans of 12 @Siraj

Comment: Answer of 12 will be : 2,2,3

Comment: Maybe you should be thinking "I'm studying recursion but it becomes very difficult because I use `exit()` instead of `return;`" — because that's the reality.  You seldom use a recursive function just once in a program (except perhaps in test programs when first learning to handle recursion).  Your function needs to return to makes its result available to the rest of the program.  If it encounters a catastrophic problem, then maybe an `exit()` is in order, but otherwise the use of `exit()` is wholly inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

if `pf` is to return it must be returned with all its calls.
So, I propose a change like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pf(int n, int d);

int main(void){
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    pf(num, 2);
    return 0;
}

void pf(int num, int i){
    if(num == 1)
        return ;
    if(num % i == 0){
        printf("%d, ", i);
        pf(num / i, i);
        return ;
    }
    if(i == 2)
        pf(num, i + 1);
    else
        pf(num, i + 2);
}
```

---

reduce code

```
void pf(int num, int i){
    if(num == 1)
        return ;
    if(num % i == 0){
        printf("%d, ", i);
        pf(num / i, i);
    } else {
        pf(num, i + 1 + (i != 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Today I join stackoverflow, and I'm really very glad to be here.
Thanks a lot @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Note that the algorithm is very slow.  For values in the range 1111000 to 1111010, it can take 32 seconds to find the prime factors of 1111004 (which are 2, 2, and 277751), where a different algorithm takes milliseconds.  When the factors are small, it seems to work OK, but when they're large, then it takes a very long time.  This is wholly unrelated to the analysis in this answer, which is fine.

Comment: And on a prime number like 1111007, it is worse than just extremely slow.  It took 7m 36s, and the process size had reached 2432748 (measured by `ps -l` on a Mac).  That's a huge program size and a very long time. I'm moderately amazed it completed (I was drafting this comment in terms of "it does not complete" when it did in fact complete).

Comment: It does not say regarding algorithm. I think It will probably stack overflow before than 32 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

I found out two problems in your code. May be it's okay after solving these two problems:

1. Replace `exit(1)` with `return 1;`
2. After `if(i==j)`, you have to do this:

> ```
> if(rem2==0) {//your code}
> else pf(num,i+1,2);
> ```

Comment: It only works till integers with 4 digits after that program crashes  and also _how can you return from a function declared as void?_

Comment: I can't develop his logic. @ameyCU

Comment: No, it is working well with 20000, which is of 5 digits

Comment: I don't think that it's declaration void is doing anything wrong in it.